# How would you display hashtag content on a website?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, hashtag

It looks from Instagram API that if you want to display hashtag content based, you can't anymore (because it requires public_content scope).

From official website: *This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).
You can find more information in the Permission Review documentation.*

What does it means company that offers this type of service?

How would you display (in a website) the hashtag content of Instagram nowdays?